# Black borders around png screenshot

Tags: java, selenium, screenshot

Below are the codes i have written to take screenshot of an active window. However, im unsure why there are black borders surrounding the image. Please help and tell me if there is any mistakes in my codes.

```
    Robot robot; //create robot instance
    robot = new Robot(); //gets and saves a reference to a new Robot    

    robot.delay(3000); //delay robot for 3 seconds 

    //get dimensions of the bounding rectangle of the specified window
    WinDef.HWND hwnd = User32.INSTANCE.GetForegroundWindow(); 
    RECT WindowDimensions = new RECT(); 
    //get screen coordinates of upper-left and lower-right corners of the window in dimensionsOfWindow
    User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowRect(hwnd, WindowDimensions); 
    //capture image of only active window
    BufferedImage screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(WindowDimensions.toRectangle());

    //write buffered image to file
    try{ 
        //File f = new File(dir + "\\screenshot " + createTimeStampStr() + ".png");  //file path of output
        File f = new File("D:\\screenshot " + createTimeStampStr() + ".png");  //file path of output
        ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, "png", f);
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think it is Robot framework, specifically this part BufferedImage screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(WindowDimensions.toRectangle()); Instead take a screenshot with Selenium itself

Comment: @SlavKurochkin i have tried using selenium itself to take screenshot but i only want to take the window itself and not the entire full page if the web page is on facebook for instance.

Comment: Just an observation.  It looks like the black border is around the image rather than on top of the image.  If you have a crop function within the API, you could probably just crop out N number of pixels and have your screenshot without the black border.

Comment: Have you tried getting the `Dimension()` object using `driver.manage().window().getSize()`. Check the [docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Window.html#getSize--).

Comment: @dale crop function will only work according to the window size, so if im using another computer with a different window size, the function will not work as expected.